# Taylor expansion of $\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)$

Tags: limits

If we apply maclaurin series for $\ln\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)$, we get $\ln(\infty)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Ordinarily we would expand the series for $\ln x$ around $1$, not around zero.  So one can use the expansion there to get a series involving $1/x$ for $\ln(1+1/x)$.  Would this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taylor Series are $k$ degree polynomial approximations for k-times-differentiable functions.

$f(x)=\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$ neither exists nor is differentiable at $x=0$, therefore it does not have a Maclaurin Series.

However, at $x=1$, it is infinitely differentiable, so the Taylor Series can be computed.